# Need to Implement Progress bar and thread

Tags: android

I had function that communicate with webservice and insertion of data to the datbase occur
during this function execution....I cant predict how much time it will take to execute the function.

The problem is that i need to show a progess bar which end when the function execution stop.It need to show progress.

Or is there any other option that show the commuction is in progress....

My function is as given below....

```
public Boolean startdownload() {    


        downloadhelper = new download_helper(this);

        downloadhelper.DownloadProblemAndReasonCode();      

        pkManifest=downloadhelper.DownloadNewManifest();        

        downloadhelper.DownloadNewMessages();


        return True;
    }
```

Also i have implement thread on the onclick event of Start button.......

```
start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Status.setText("Download in Progress....");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {

                                startdownload();
                                onStop();
                                isRunning=false;
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            t.toString();
                        }

                    }
                   }).start();              

                if (isRunning=false)
                {
                    Status.setText("Download Completed");
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

the easier way to do this is to use Asyntask concept of android and very easy to implement 
refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
  //Take one progress bar Display here

new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {

                            startdownload();
                            onStop();
                            isRunning=false;
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        t.toString();
                    }

                }
               }).start();              

            if (isRunning=false)
            {
                Status.setText("Download Completed");
            }
   handler.sendEmptyMessagetrue(0);

        }
//Now take handler class here to dismiss() progress bar when worked finish in thread
private Handler handler()=new Handler(){
override onhandlerMsge();dissmiss dialog in this method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `ProgressBar` somewhere in your layout and when you are ready to do your network communication you call `mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` Once your finished call `mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

An alternative is to use the progress bar in the Android system bar. To do that in `onCreate()` of your Activity call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)` before calling `setContentView()` Then you can call `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean)` anywhere from your activity.

Comment: Using the system bar is a great way to reduce clutter AND prevent the annoying flicker that can happen if the progress happens quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Beside `Asynctask`, you can use `Handler` and its `handleMessage()`. Inside your worker thread, send message to the `Handler` to display progress and notify it when the worker thread ends

Answer (score 0):

```
showLoading();// Calling showdialog before downloading..
        Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run() {

                // Code for download....

                // After download UI thread will call
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                    @Override 
                    public void run() { 
                     dialog.cancel();
                     alertbox("Info","Download Completed");
                    } 
                });
            }};
            t.start();

public ProgressDialog dialog;
    public  void showLoading () {


            // prepare the dialog box
            //ProgressDialog 
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

            // make the progress bar cancelable
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

            // set a message text
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait while Downloading..");


            // show it
            dialog.show();




        }
protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage)
   {
   new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setMessage(mymessage)
      .setTitle(title)
      .setCancelable(true)
      .setNeutralButton("OK",
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){}
         })
      .show();
   }
```

Edit:19 Aug 2011
You can cancel progress dialog using following code. Please try

```
dialog.setButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment,its works now....but I had given this the onclisk on one start button as the progress dialog comes in front didnt able to click the stop button to stop the action.....